# How to make a pattern for replace image Tag

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace img tag.
Orginal tag is for example :

```
<img src="index.php?act=img&amp;sub=article&id=35558" width="150" height="172">
```

then i want to replace it  to :

```
<img src="index.php?act=img&amp;sub=article&amp;id=35558" style="width: 150px; height: 172"/>
```

Id in src is changable.
I dont know how to define proper pattern , i've tried several but none was worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$img1 = '<img src="index.php?act=img&amp;sub=article&id=35558" width="150" height="172">';
$img2 = preg_replace('/\<img([^>]+)(width|height)="(\d+)"([^>]*)(width|height)="(\d+)"([^>]*)\>/i', '<img$1 style="$2:$3px;$5:$6px"$4$7>', $img1);
```

The order of parameters(or any additional) does not matter here.

Comment: What if the image tag has any other attribute as well? Or it already has a style tag?

Comment: Benjamin, you answer is definitely right. But not all tasks require such approach. We don't know what's Karol's goal, but his question is plain - he has a number of lines of same pattern and needs to make some replacement. Regular expressions are perfect here.

Comment: Thank you. It works very good. My goal was simple , i needed to replace tags in only one format so i thought regex was fit it best.

Answer (score 2):

Please, regular expressions are not the right tool for this sort of thing. Regular expressions should be used when you are parsing simple things, HTML is not a regular language anyway.

Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) about parsing HTML with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are looking for a regular expression pattern so you can use preg_match to reconstruct the tag? In that case something like this should would:

```
preg_match('/src="(.+?)".+?width="(.+?)".+?height="(.+?)"/i', $str, $matches);
```

However, the moment these attributes start changing order, this regular expression won't work anymore. If possible, it would be better to parse the HTML through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This works the way to wanted:P But not recommended to use regex to serve your purpose.

```
<?php
$string = '<img src="index.php?act=img&amp;sub=article&id=35558" width="150" height="172">';
echo $resultString = preg_replace(array('/\&id\b/i','/width="150" height="172"/i'), array('&amp;id','style="width: 150px; height: 172"'), $string);
```